# Use ADDRESS (or similar) to return full column address

Tags: excel

Currently I use a cell macro like this:

```excel
=SUM(COMPLAINTDATA!D:D)
```

to sum up a full column. `COMPLAINTDATA` is the name of the sheet. I want to store the column number (`4`) in a cell, so that it can be used in various macros. The input format is changing sometimes and I don't want to edit all cell macros.

```
A B          C
1 row to sum 4
2
3
```

Is there a way to do this easily, I can't find the relevant function. `ADDRESS` seems to be the way, but I can't figure out how to return something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column to sum can change from time to time, you can use `INDIRECT` formula. `INDIRECT` lets you create cell or range reference "on the fly".

First, store your column letter in some other cell, eg. in a separate sheet (lets say it will be in  A1 cell in a sheet named `'ConfigSheet'`  - insert some letter there, eg. `D` like in your example.

Then update your sum formula so it looks like this:

```excel
=SUM(INDIRECT("COMPLAINTDATA!"&ConfigSheet!$A$1&":"&ConfigSheet!$A$1))
```

That should do what you need.

More information on this function in the [official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/article/474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ns=EXCEL&version=90).

Comment: Thanks - I still need to find a way through the Office documentation. Most of the commands have names which I would never ever think of.